# Java Swing JEditorPane: manipulating styled documents

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I have model that is a queue of Strings associated with enum types.

I'm trying to display that model in a JEditorPane, with each element in the queue as a separate HTML paragraph that has attributes based based on the associated enum type.

However, my updating methods are not doing what I want.  I tried writing the HTML strings directly to the document (e.g., I take the Strings, prepend `<p style="color:red">` and append `</p>` and then insert them at the end of the document), but that gives me the html tags in the output (instead of as formatting) - which of course is inconsistent with the result of putting the tags on the string that I use construct the document with JEditorPane("text/html",String foo).  I've also tried inserting with an AttributeSet, but apparently I'm doing that wrong as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had much luck playing with HTML in a JEditorPane. I just use attributes in a JTextPane. Something like:

```
SimpleAttributSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

try
{
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nSome more text", keyWord );
}
catch(Exception e) {}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks; I would still like to eventually support HTML formatting, but that's not necessary at the moment and I think I've kept the concerns separate enough that it'll be a simple substitution later.

Comment: This link show my best effort at using the HTMLEditorKit. Maybe you can figure it out better than me: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=57&threadID=707909