# How do I apply styles to do syntax coloring in a JEditorPane with Netbeans Java editor kit (Javakit)?

Tags: java, swing, syntax-highlighting, lexer, netbeans-platform

I want to achieve syntax coloring inside in a JEditorPane that is already equipped with Netbeans Java editor kit (class org.netbeans.modules.editor.java.JavaKit). I noticed that when the JEditorPane has the RTF editor kit instead, the keywords are colored (see this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67025502/8315843). The thing is that Netbeans has an interesting component called the diff view that I want to use, and that diff view uses two JEditorPanes that come equipped with this Javakit which does not seem to offer syntax coloring.

Inside the sample code below, I show 2 possible execution paths :

- With the RTF editor kit, you see the keyword public colored in blue
- With the Netbeans Javakit, you see it didn't work

As for the input, I use a very minialist class "public class Hello {}" which is in the variable named "text".

```
    boolean useNetbeansJavakit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Use Netbeans Javakit ?") == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;

    JFrame f = new JFrame("JAVA Syntax Coloring");

    // Create the StyleContext, the document and the pane
    StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
    final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
    JEditorPane pane;
    if (useNetbeansJavakit) {
        pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setEditorKit(CloneableEditorSupport.getEditorKit("text/x-java"));
    } else {
        pane = new JEditorPane("text/rtf", "");
    }

    System.out.println(pane.getEditorKit());
    pane.setDocument(doc);

    // Create and add the constant width style
    final Style cwStyle = sc.addStyle("ConstantWidth", null);
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(cwStyle, "monospaced");
    StyleConstants.setForeground(cwStyle, Color.blue);

    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Add the text to the document
                    doc.insertString(0, text, null);

                    // Only color the word public for now in a hardcoded style
                    doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 6, cwStyle, false);

                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception when constructing document: " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pane));
    f.setSize(400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
public static final String text = "public class Hello {}";
```

Here is the gradle build file :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")
    implementation 'org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-java-editor:RELEASE123'
    implementation 'org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-editor-mimelookup-impl:RELEASE123'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.10'
}
```

I've been working on trying to use the lexer-based syntax highlighter, but I do not know how to use, I can only guess how to use it like below, but I just don't understand how it doesn't just come natively. In the netbeans library, everything seems to be there to do some syntax coloring (see class org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2.highlighting.SyntaxHighlighting, but I can't find any explanation on how to use it).
In the code below, I tokenize the text into identifiers and check for keywords, and then put the coloring information for the keyword tokens.

```
    JFrame f = new JFrame("JAVA Syntax Coloring");
    // Create the StyleContext, the document and the pane
    StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
    final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
    JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
    pane.setEditorKit(CloneableEditorSupport.getEditorKit("text/x-java"));
    System.out.println(pane.getEditorKit());
    pane.setDocument(doc);
    LexerBasedHighlightLayer lexerBasedHighlightLayer = (LexerBasedHighlightLayer) doc.getProperty(SemanticHighlighter.class);
    HashMap<Token, Coloring> colorings = new HashMap<>(lexerBasedHighlightLayer.getColorings());
    Language<JavaTokenId> java = JavaTokenId.language();
    TokenHierarchy<String> th = TokenHierarchy.create(text, java);
    TokenSequence<JavaTokenId> ts = th.tokenSequence(java);
    while (ts.moveNext()) {
        Token<JavaTokenId> token = ts.token();
        String tokenText = token.text().toString();
        if (tokenText.matches(
                "(abstract|continue|for|new|switch|assert|default|goto|package|synchronized|boolean|do|if|private|this|break|double|implements|protected|throw|byte|else|import|public|throws|case|enum|instanceof|return|transient|catch|extends|int|short|try|char|final|interface|static|void|class|finally|long|strictfp|volatile|const|float|native|super|while)")) {
            ColoringAttributes colorAttr = EnumUtils.getEnum(ColoringAttributes.class, tokenText.toUpperCase());
            if (colorAttr != null) {
                Coloring coloring = ColoringAttributes.add(ColoringAttributes.empty(), colorAttr);
                colorings.put(token, coloring);
            }
        }
    }
    lexerBasedHighlightLayer.setColorings(colorings, colorings.keySet(), null);

    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Add the text to the document
                    doc.insertString(0, text, null);

                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception when constructing document: " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pane));
    f.setSize(400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
public static final String text = "public class Hello {}";
```

The color information is configured in XML files in the jar org-netbeans-modules-java-editor-RELEASE123.jar. To configure my own colors, I copied the org/netbeans/modules/java/editor/resources directory from the jar to my workspace at src/main/resources/org/netbeans/modules/java/editor/resources.

Inside the file src/main/resources/org/netbeans/modules/java/editor/resources/fontsColors.xml I added an attribute foreColor="blue" to the mod-public to try and highlight the keyword public to blue :

```
<fontcolor name="mod-public"  foreColor="blue" />
```

I also modified the file fontsColors-highlighting.xml of the same directory so now it looks like this :

```
<fontscolors>
    <fontcolor name="remove-surround-code-delete" foreColor="ffB4B4B4" bgColor="ffF5F5F5"/>
    <fontcolor name="remove-surround-code-remain" bgColor="ffCCFFCC"/>
    <fontcolor name="mod-public" foreColor="blue" />
</fontscolors>
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here :

https://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-lexer/org/netbeans/api/lexer/TokenHierarchy.html

> The document may define a top language by doing
> doc.putProperty("mimeType", mimeType) (a language defined for the
> given mime type will be searched and used) or by doing
> putProperty(Language.class, language). Otherwise the returned
> hierarchy will be inactive and TokenHierarchy.tokenSequence() will
> return null.

And this TokenHierarchy.get(doc) is called in the constructor of SyntaxHighlighting :

```
/** Creates a new instance of SyntaxHighlighting */
public SyntaxHighlighting(Document document) {
    this.document = document;
    String mimeType = (String) document.getProperty("mimeType"); //NOI18N
    if (mimeType != null && mimeType.startsWith("test")) { //NOI18N
        this.mimeTypeForOptions = mimeType;
    } else {
        this.mimeTypeForOptions = null;
    }
    
    // Start listening on changes in global colorings since they may affect colorings for target language
    findFCSInfo("", null);

    hierarchy = TokenHierarchy.get(document);
    hierarchy.addTokenHierarchyListener(WeakListeners.create(TokenHierarchyListener.class, this, hierarchy));
}
```

Howerver just setting the mime type didn't work for me.
This is what worked for me :

```
doc.putProperty(Language.class, JavaTokenId.language());
```

Also there is no need to tokenize, the netbeans library does all the job and the code is reduced to the following :

```
public void doSyntaxColoring(String fileName) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("JAVA Syntax Coloring");

    DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
    doc.putProperty(Language.class, JavaTokenId.language());
    JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
    pane.setEditorKit(CloneableEditorSupport.getEditorKit(JavaKit.JAVA_MIME_TYPE));
    pane.setDocument(doc);

    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName)) {

                    String text = IOUtils.toString(fileReader);
                    // Add the text to the document
                    doc.insertString(0, text, null);

                } catch (BadLocationException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception when constructing document: " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pane));
    f.setSize(400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

And the gradle build file :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")
    implementation 'org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-java-editor:RELEASE123'
    implementation 'org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-editor-mimelookup-impl:RELEASE123'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.10'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0'
}
```

Also no need to do anything in the resource files (unless maybe for color change)